# Eclipse Neon freezes and crashes computer on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, eclipse

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (`64 bit, 4.4.0-31-generic`) and downloaded the eclipse neon installer and installed eclipse (not as root) in the `~/opt/` directory I created. Eclipse works fine and I am programming in Java, but after a little while (sometimes a few minutes, sometimes 30 minutes) eclipse suddenly crashes. My mouse moves but I can't click anything anywhere. About 10 seconds later the mouse also crashes and stops moving and the computer becomes unresponsive, and which point I have to hold the power button to turn off the laptop and start it up again.

Any ideas what this might be or possible fixes? I've tried reinstalling eclipse (by removing the installation directory and reinstalling), I've redownloaded the installer again also but no luck. I haven't experienced this problem with other applications yet so I'm presuming it's an eclipse problem.

I've installed `openjdk-8-jre` and `openjdk-8-jdk.`

EDIT: Apparently it's been marked as a duplicate question as what to do when Ubuntu crashes, but this issue has been arising while using eclipse. I'm not asking what I should do when it crashes, I'm asking what I should do to stop it crashing in the first place.

Comment: I have 16 GB of RAM, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'm aware Eclipse Neon did have an issue with unresponsive shortcuts with GTK3. It would be worth testing to see if Eclipse with GTK3 is the issue here. You can launch Eclipse using GTK2 with `SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse` just to see if there's any difference.

Comment: @gsxruk, thanks for the suggestion. It appears to be working now. I'll continue using it tomorrow and if I don't have a crash I'll write it as an answer and accept

Comment: @Billy Good to hear. You'll have to flag for moderator intervention to add a new answer as the question has now been set as a "duplicate". Also, it would be worth adding a bug report with eclipse if you find this is the issue.

Comment: I just had a random crash (no eclipse) when starting up from suspend that might be related. It's the first time it's happened without eclipse so I'll hold out. I've updated the kernel to 4.6 (I've read of problems related to intel graphics). Let's see what happens now...

Comment: I have had to revert back to 4.4. Worked on eclipse for about an hour and then had the crash again (using SWT_GTK3=0) :(

Comment: I had wrongly voted to close this as a duplicate of [that way more general question that doesn't really answer this](https://askubuntu.com/q/4408), and was the first to do so (setting the process in motion). So I believe I'm the main person responsible for this mistake--my apologies! Depending on the results of further investigation, I strongly suspect this will turn out to be a bug, so it [might end up being re-closed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1317). In your case, that general freeze troubleshooting advice would not likely have helped (but that is probably why I made this mistake). Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

try add this to eclipse.ini:

`-XX:MaxPermSize=768m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

work for me!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You could improve this answer by explaining why these settings would help the problem. :)